# Sorting by a Object field in a Vector of Vector of Objects

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a `vector<vector<Edge> >graph` in my Edge object i have 3 int fields called height weight length. I have already populated my vector with elements and now i want to sort my vector in terms of weight from largest to smallest. How would i be able to do so.

Comment: For `std::vector<Edge> v` you could use `std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](Edge const& lhs, Edge const&  rhs) { return lhs.weight > rhs.weight; })`

Comment: Do you want to sort each row in separate?

Comment: So currently after all data has been entered the vector is sorted by length. For example the first line 0 , 12 , 21 2nd line being 1, 13, 22 each number being length , height, weight respectively. Is it possible to sort them so that when i print it will be  1, 13 ,22 first line then  0 ,12, 21 2nd line and so on

Comment: I other words, do you want to sort your lines by first element's weight? In your example "line 0 , 12 , 21 2nd line being 1, 13, 22" it is graph[0][0], graph[1][0]?

Comment: You must specify one comparator for 2 vectors of vector and one comparator for a vector of Edge.

Comment: @jdoe, if answer for my previous question is yes, then `std::sort(graph.begin(), graph.end(), [](std::vector<Edge> const& lhs, std::vector<Edge> const& rhs) { return lhs.front().weight > rhs.front().weight; })`

Comment: @jdoe If you are cpp14 enabled, then `std::sort(graph.begin(), graph.end(), [](auto const& lhs, auto const& rhs) { return lhs.front().weight > rhs.front().weight; })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `Edge` looks something like

```
struct Edge {
    int height, weight, length;
}
```

Add a function like

```
bool compareWeight(const Edge& l, const Edge& r) {
    return l.weight > r.weight;
}
```

And use `sort` from [algorithm](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/)

```
for(int i = 0; i < graph.size(); i++) {
    std::sort(graph[i].begin(), graph[i].end(), compareWeight);
}
```

That will sort each vector of `Edge`'s by weight.

Comment: `l.weight > r.weight` descending order

Comment: So i have my Edge object implementation and my graph vector in two different h files where would i add the function compareWeight

Comment: You also forgot to specify return type for your comparator. The author tagged question with `cpp11`, you could use lambda.

Comment: @nicolai lambda could be used but comparing by weight seems like the kind of thing that will be done in more than one place and could use a function of it own.

Comment: @jdoe preferably in the header file containing the `Edge` class as it directly relates to `Edge`. Ideally `compareWeight` could be added as a static member function to the `Edge` class.

Comment: @ConfusedByCode from that perspective you are right. I just wanted to say, that there is nothing from cpp11 in your example. At least, you could employ cpp11 range for loop: `for (auto &row : graph) { std::sort(row.begin(), row.end(), &compareWeight); }`

Answer (score 0):

To do so your class `Edge` must have overloaded operator `<`.
And then you can just use `sort()` from `#include <algorithm>`

```
sort(graph.begin(), graph.end());
```

Also make sense to overload other operators as `>`, `>=`, `<=`, `==`, `!=`.

Comment: You do not need to overload the `<` operator. What if sometimes you want to sort by height or length or some combination of the two? It makes more sense to use a function that compares the weight and pass that to sort.

Comment: The right approach is to provide a comparator function to the `std::sort`.